# CSS tabs with jquery (ios compatible)

Tags: jquery, css, ios, mobile, tabs

I am trying to make my css tabs compatible for mobile devices, especially for IOS. Also I want to use 3 different tabs on my page. I have no jquery knowledge, so I tried to find an example. The best example I found was using this structure;

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#" name="tab1">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab2">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab3">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab4">Four</a></li>    
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
<div id="tab1">...</div>
<div id="tab2">...</div>
<div id="tab3">...</div>
<div id="tab4">...</div>
</div>
```

and its jQuery is;

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return       
        }
        else{             
        $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

There is a small problem. I do not want to use id for tabs. I changed id with classes then modified the CSS. I tried to modify the script but it wont work:(
There are three different tab groups on my page, that's why I am changing it to classes.
My new tabs are;

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#" name="tab1">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab2">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab3">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab4">Four</a></li>    
</ul>

<div class="tabs_content"> 
<div id="tab1">...</div>
<div id="tab2">...</div>
<div id="tab3">...</div>
<div id="tab4">...</div>
</div>
```

And tried to change jQuery as;

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs_content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $(".tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $(".tabs_content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

    $('.tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return       
        }
        else{             
        $(".tabs_content div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $(".tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Can you please help me with the jQuery? Or show me a better example for multiple tab tables within the same page?
Thanx in advance

edit: With the change now when I use one tab group other tab groups' contents are hidden :)

And this is the CSS file;

```
    .tabs{
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .tabs li{
      float: left;
      margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
    }

    .tabs a{
      position: relative;
      background: #ddd;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
      padding: .7em 3.5em;
      float: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #444;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8);
      border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }

    .tabs a:hover,
    .tabs a:hover::after,
    .tabs a:focus,
    .tabs a:focus::after{
      background: #fff;
    }

    .tabs a:focus{
      outline: 0;
    }

    .tabs a::after{
      content:'';
      position:absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      right: -.5em;  
      bottom: 0;
      width: 1em;
      background: #ddd;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      transform: skew(10deg);
      border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;  
    }

    .tabs #current a,
    .tabs #current a::after{
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .tabs_content
    {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 2em;
        height: 220px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2; 
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }

My new settings are;

Script is;

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function(){
        //INIT IS NOT NECESSARY IF YOU FOLLOW MY CODE

    $("#tabs a").click(function(){
        //ADD ACTIVE CLASS
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        //SHOW CONTENT
        $(".content-holder").removeClass("current");
        var myIndex = $(this).parent().index(); // gets the index of the LI clicked
        $(".content-holder").eq(myIndex).fadeIn();
    });
    });
    </script>
HTML is;

        <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab current"><a href="#" name="tab1">One</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#" name="tab2">Two</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#" name="tab3">Three</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#" name="tab4">Four</a></li>    
        </ul>

        <div class="content"> 
        <div class="content-holder current" id="tab1">content1</div>
        <div class="content-holder" id="tab2">content2</div>
        <div class="content-holder" id="tab3">content3</div>
        <div class="content-holder" id="tab4">content4</div>
        </div>


and my css is;
.tabs{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tabs li{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
}

.tabs a{
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
  padding: .7em 3.5em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a:hover::after,
.tabs a:focus,
.tabs a:focus::after{
  background: #fff;
}

.tabs a:focus{
  outline: 0;
}

.tabs a::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: -.5em;  
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  transform: skew(10deg);
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;  
}

.tabs #current a,
.tabs #current a::after{
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}

.content
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2em;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2; 
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.content-holder {
    display:none;
}
.content-holder.current {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup a plugin that can handle multiple tab sets.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.tabset = function () {
        var $tabsets = $(this);
        $tabsets.each(function (i) {
            var $tabs = $('li.tab a', this);
            $tabs.click(function (e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                    panels = $.map($tabs, function (val, i) {
                        return $(val).attr('href');
                    });
                $(panels.join(',')).hide();
                $tabs.removeClass('selected');
                $this.addClass('selected').blur();
                $($this.attr('href')).show();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }).first().triggerHandler('click');
        });
      };
})(jQuery);
```

You'll have to wrap your html in a div containing both the tabs and the content. Also you need to update your anchors to use a standard hash tag, see below:

```
<div class="tabset">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#tab1">One</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2">Two</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#tab3">Three</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#tab4">Four</a></li>    
    </ul>

    <div class="panel" id="tab1">...</div>
    <div class="panel" id="tab2">...</div>
    <div class="panel" id="tab3">...</div>
    <div class="panel" id="tab4">...</div>
</div>
```

You can call it like so:

```
$('div.tabset').tabset();
```

You can see a working example including three tab sets at: http://jsfiddle.net/rustyjeans/XVp5X/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI to the rescue: jqueryui.com/demos/tabs
They're nestable out of the box.

See this example: http://jsbin.com/ubaqe found [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-tabs-is-nesting-possible).

[You say that you "changed id with classes then modified the CSS" – it'd be helpful to see these changes. Where you pasted your "new tabs", nothing appears to be different, other than that you've left out the jQuery!]

[Having only 3 tabs doesn't explain why you'd rather use classes than IDs.]

[If you leave the code as is, and just trim out the 4th tab `<li>` and `<div>` from the html, the existing jQuery should effectively show whatever you place in the divs (where there are now elipses) within the #content.]

Comment: I have 3 tabs in one tab group. I want to use more than one tab group in the page. like,<br />News Tab Group, Products Tab Group and Services Tab Group.<br /> all these group would have 3 tabs inside.

Comment: In the jQuery, you're referencing .tabs_content, which does not correspond with the class you've given the content div.

Comment: See this example: http://jsbin.com/ubaqe found here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-tabs-is-nesting-possible

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your "current" to a class rather than using an ID.

```
$(function(){
    //INIT IS NOT NECESSARY IF YOU FOLLOW MY CODE

    $("#tabs a").click(function(){
        //ADD ACTIVE CLASS
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        //SHOW CONTENT
        $(".content-holder").removeClass("current"):
        var myID = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#" + myID).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

I'd setup your HTML initially like this, and you could get rid of the unneccesary JS inits

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab current"><a href="#" name="tab1">One</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#" name="tab2">Two</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#" name="tab3">Three</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#" name="tab4">Four</a></li>    
</ul>

<div class="content"> 
    <div class="content-holder current" id="tab1">...</div>
    <div class="content-holder" id="tab2">...</div>
    <div class="content-holder" id="tab3">...</div>
    <div class="content-holder" id="tab4">...</div>
</div>
```

Setup CSS like this:

```
.content-holder {
    display:none;
}
.content-holder.current {
    display:block;
}
```

if your content containers always follow the same order as your navigation, you could also just do $.index() and use that to set your actives... for example:

```
$("#tabs a").click(function(){
    //ADD ACTIVE CLASS
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    //SHOW CONTENT
    $(".content-holder").removeClass("current");
    var myIndex = $(this).parent().index(); // gets the index of the LI clicked
    $(".content-holder").eq(myIndex).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Joel, so would this help me use multiple tab groups on the same page?

Comment: yes, it would allow for that. It also allows you to simply use jQuery .addClass and .removeClass, and do all your show/hiding based on CSS. so if your .current then the css .class.current { display:block } 

I usually use class="active" but "current" works as well

Comment: .hide() method adds the an inline style property, and sets it to display:none. I personally like to use classes rather than inline styling.

Comment: one dumb question:) which one should I use? cause it is not working now <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: No error message. When I try it in FF it none of the tabs seems to get active but <div class="content-holder current" id="tab1">content1</div> is displayed,when I click on a  tab get active(changes color) but its content wont load

Comment: can you put all your code into a JSFiddle? Check out jsfiddle.net and then post your link here, will help me debug it